# using **kwargs to create Class attributes

Tags: python, class, init, keyword-argument

here is my beginner problem:
I want to create a class with numerous attributes using a dictionary.
Instead of using **def **init**(self, att1, att2...)** I'm trying to do:

```
class Promo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k in kwargs:
            self.k = kwargs[k]
```

passing a dictionary `{att1:'xxxx', att2:'yyyy' , .....}` as argument.
Since I have a dozen of named arguments in each dictionary, how can I use **kwargs in my code?
Thanks for you advice!!
de716

Comment: `setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])`…

Comment: thank you so much, I just found another way with:
self.__dict__.update(kwargs) !!